# Keep the good work up / Keep up the good work - Are they both grammatical?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases, expressions

I have always heard “Keep up the good work”, but “Keep the good work up” also sounds fine to me. Is it acceptable?

Comment: *Keep it up*, or *Keep up the...* are the most common.

Answer (score 9):

> 1. Keep it up
> 2. Keep up the good work.
> 3. Keep the good work up.

This type of verb plus preposition combination is often called a *separable phrasal verb* in traditional grammar. It is called this because we can put the complement noun in between the verb and the preposition - or we can put it *after* preposition. Of course, however, when the complement is a pronoun, it must go in between the verb and the preposition:

- **put** the pen **down**.
- **put down** the pen.
- **put** it **down**.
- **put down** it. (ungrammatical).

However, although we can put the noun phrase complement, either before or after the preposition, we strongly prefer to put *long* noun phrases *after* the preposition:

- He **rolled** the old Venetian rug **up**. (grammatical but awkward)
- He **rolled up** the old Venetian rug. (grammatical, not awkward)

This means that, all things considered, we would tend to favour sentence (2) over sentence (3).

As an exhortation to our friends - as an imperative - *keep up the good work* might be considered a fixed phrase. However, when being used in a normal sentence *to keep the good work up* is not all that jarring, just a little awkward. It can be seen in published works. [You can see it here](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22keep+the+good+work+up+%22), for example.

Nonetheless, *the good work* is a long enough noun phrase for us to strongly prefer to put it at the end of the sentence. Here is an Ngram for *keep up the good work* versus *keep the good work up*. (Not that Ngrams should be taken too seriously!):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Actually, "keep the good work up" is flat **wrong**.

**Keep up** is a prepositional phrasal verb meaning to continue at the same level or pace (definition from thefreedictionary.com). Unlike particle phrasal verbs, prepositional phrasal verbs cannot be split apart.

Consider the following sentence:

> Keep up with me.

You cannot move **up** away from **keep** without changing the meaning of the sentence.

> Keep with me up.

"Keep up the good work" is *not* an idiom. An idiom is an expression that cannot be understood from its elements. "Keep tabs on" is an idiom. "Keep up the good work" actually *can* be understood from its elements.

Comment: There are multiple uses of *keep up*. ODO has an entry for *[keep something up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/keep-something-up)*, "to continue a course of action"; then there is to *[keep up with sth](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/keep-up-with)*, to stay aware of it, and then there is *[keep up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/keep-up)*, to maintain a pace. Your example could reflect case #2 or #3, but does not address #1, which is clearly acceptable.

Comment: Hm, ok. I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 3):

“Keep the good work up” is not exactly *wrong*, but neither is it *idiomatic English*. I think most native speakers would stick with “Keep up the good work”.

Answer (score 3):

**Keep up** is a general idiom meaning to maintain or stay abreast of.

```
Keep up speed. (Do not slow down, road sign on gentle uphill.)
Keep up with your homework. (Don't fall behind.)
```

*Keep the good work up* is not idiomatic, because we're used to **keep up** as a unit.

Answer (score 2):

1. Some discourage the practice of ending a sentence with a preposition (by moving the preposition to the end, in fact).
2. In this idiomatic expression, the focus is on the phrasal verb *keep up* and by splitting it, the very essence of the sentiment is lost.

In any case, as already noted in (1) above, the expression [*keep up the good work*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Keep+up+the+good+work) (TFD) is an idiom, so use it as it is for the idiomatic effect. Compare: *[keep it up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Keep+it+up)*